# Making an array out of a custom class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
import java.io.*;

public class workPoS {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dataList[] some_list = new dataList[10];

        for (int x = 0; x < some_list.length; x++) {
            some_list[x].firstName = "John";
            some_list[x].middleName = "Jacob";
            some_list[x].lastName = "Jingle-Heimer-Schmidt";
            some_list[x].age = 101;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < some_list.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(some_list[x].firstName + " "
                    + some_list[x].middleName + " " + some_list[x].lastName
                    + " Age: " + some_list[x].age);
        }

    }

    public class dataList {
        String firstName, middleName, lastName;
        int age;

        public dataList() {
            firstName = "";
            middleName = "";
            lastName = "";
            age = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at workPoS.main(workPoS.java:12)**

This is line 12:

```
some_list[x].firstName = "John";
```

It seems that I am able to access some_list[x], but as soon as I specify a constructor, some_list[x].firstName, the result is a null value.

Am I simply referencing the constructor value incorrectly?
If so, what is the correct way to do so?

Thanks guys!

Comment: is android an accurate tag? The entrance point for an Android application isn't `main` like it is for a desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using both the classes in the same .java file, the try this code

> import java.io.*;
>
> public class workPoS {
>
> ```
> public workPoS() { 
>   super();
> ```
>
> }
>
> /**
>        * @param args
>        */
>       public static void main(String[] args) {
>         workPoS wp = new workPoS();
>         dataList[] some_list = new dataList[10];
>
> ```
>     for (int x = 0; x < some_list.length; x++) {
>       some_list[x] = wp.new dataList();
>         some_list[x].firstName = "John";
>         some_list[x].middleName = "Jacob";
>         some_list[x].lastName = "Jingle-Heimer-Schmidt";
>         some_list[x].age = 101;
>     }
>
>     for (int x = 0; x < some_list.length; x++) {
>         System.out.println(some_list[x].firstName + " "
>                 + some_list[x].middleName + " " + some_list[x].lastName
>                 + " Age: " + some_list[x].age);
>     }
>
> }
>
> public class dataList {
>     String firstName, middleName, lastName;
>     int age;
>
>     public dataList() {
>         firstName = "";
>         middleName = "";
>         lastName = "";
>         age = 0;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for actually taking the time to solve the problem rather than assume I'm a complete idiot.

Answer (score 7):

Look here:

```
dataList[] some_list = new dataList[10];

for (int x = 0; x < some_list.length; x++) {
    some_list[x].firstName = "John";
```

You've created the array - but all the elements will be null references. You talk about "referencing the constructor value incorrectly" - you're not *calling* the constructor at all. You should have:

```
for (int x = 0; x < some_list.length; x++) {
    some_list[x] = new dataList();
    some_list[x].firstName = "John";
```

See the [Java Tutorial for Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for more information.

(You should also fix your names to follow Java naming conventions, and make your fields private, but that's a different matter...)